# Redirect to my site

Tags: java, http, redirect, jmenuitem

I have a `JMenuItem` which contains for example the label "mySite.com".

I added to it a listener to him like that :

```
 ...addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            /* do something */
        }
    });
```

So now I want to when I click to it, it redirect me to the http:/ /mySite.com.

Someone can enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29), which..

> Launches the default browser to display a `URI`. If the default browser is not able to handle the specified `URI`, the application registered for handling `URIs` of the specified type is invoked. The application is determined from the protocol and path of the `URI`, as defined by the `URI` class.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for working examples. The examples use buttons but the basic ActionListener code would be the same. You would want to use the "Browse" feature.